# Find the File from user input

Tags: java

I am new to Java File Handling and I am planning to make a switch case in which the user will have to Press 1: to Create a File, Press 2: To Find the Created File and Write the File, and Press 3: To Display the file to the console. This is my practiced code, I am stuck with finding the file, I have no idea what to do anymore, here is my code. I am Stuck with Case 2.

switch(pickaNum) {
case 1: // Create a File
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter the Name of the File You Want to Create: ");
String fileName;
fileName = input.nextLine();
fileName = fileName + ".txt";
File file = new File(fileName);
file.createNewFile();
System.exit(0);

```
 break;
 case 2: // Find and Write Text
 //String text;
  Scanner sc1 = new Scanner(System.in);
 System.out.println("Name of the File you Want to Write? ");
 String name = sc1.nextLine();

 
 System.out.println("Please Write Text(s) Here: ");
 String text = sc1.nextLine();
 name = text;
 FileWriter fw = new FileWriter(name);
 fw.write(name);
 fw.close();
 
break;
case 3:
```

Comment: You first ask the user to enter the name, then the text, then you do `name = text;`, so you overwrite the value of the variable `name` with what's in `text`. Why? Remove that line, and change `fw.write(name);` into `fw.write(text);`